# Getting data stored between particular time

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, oracle

I'm storing the time in the attendance table in this format (00:00:00)..
Now i need to find the login data stored before 09:00:00.

I'm using this query to find the data.

```
SELECT user_name, 
       time_in 
  FROM attendance 
 WHERE user_name='Vignesh' 
  AND  time_in < 09:20:59
```

This thing is not working for me.  Is there any other method to get the data's before 09:00:00 from the DB?

Comment: type: time
default: 00:00:00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to enclose it in quotes:

```
AND  time_in < '09:20:59'
               ^--------^--- single quote char
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html

> MySQL recognizes [TIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in `'D HH:MM:SS'` format. You can also use one of the following “relaxed” syntaxes: `'HH:MM:SS'`, `'HH:MM'`, `'D HH:MM'`, `'D HH'`, or `'SS'`. Here `D` represents days and can have a value from 0 to 34.
> - As a string with no delimiters in `'HHMMSS'` format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, `'101112'` is understood as `'10:11:12'`, but `'109712'` is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part) and becomes `'00:00:00'`.
> - As a number in `HHMMSS` format, provided that it makes sense as a time. For example, `101112` is understood as `'10:11:12'`. The following alternative formats are also understood: `SS`, `MMSS`, or `HHMMSS`.

Comment: Once i fetch records Is there any other method to validate those dates in PHP? I have a idea to color the data before 9 am for easy reference.

Comment: @Vignesh Gopalakrishnan: as soon as it's a string in format `'HH:MM:SS'` you can just perform a direct comparison like `if ($time < '09:00:00') { ... }`

Comment: @ zerkms: Thankyou sir. Let me give a try.!!

Answer (score 2):

try do this

```
    SELECT user_name, 
   time_in 
   FROM attendance 
 WHERE user_name='Vignesh' 
  AND  time_in < '09:20:59'
```

EDIT :

or you can also use this

```
        SELECT user_name,time_in
   FROM attendance 
   WHERE user_name='Vignesh' 
    AND startTime < TIME_FORMAT("00:00:00","%H:%i:%s") 
     AND endTime > TIME_FORMAT("05:00:00","%H:%i:%s")
```

Comment: time_in BETWEEN '09:20:59' AND '09:00:00'
This is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have use the following syntax to get data between two dates,

**Date between '2011/02/25' and '2011/02/27'**

Use datetime for the above one.. it will work.... (timestamp)

Or use like below,

```
SELECT id FROM Parts WHERE (Time < EndTime) AND (Time > BeginTime) ORDER BY Time;
```

Comment: I am asking the data with respect to time.  Not date. Thankyou for your reply